# Looking for a proof for the following apparent relationships between the integral of survival and quantile functions with moments

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Given a probability distribution (at least for non-negative real-valued ones) it can be proven that
$$
\int_0^\infty S(x) dx = E(X)
$$
Letting $p = F(x)$ for a given $x$, this is equivalent to
$$
\int_0^1 F^{-1}(p) dp = E(X)
$$
In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344699/can-any-function-of-the-second-moment-of-a-random-variable-be-recovered-from-its) I was interested in finding second moment equivalents. For my purposes then, dealing with the survival function instead of the quantile function was sufficient.

Recently, I had reason to revisit the question, and empirical experimentation implies the following identities hold in general:
$$
\int_0^\infty xS(x) dx = \frac{E(X^2)}{2}\\
\int_0^1 \left[F^{-1}(p)\right]^2 dp = E(X^2)
$$
However, I am not able to find my way through the calculus to prove it in the general case. In the simple case, we can use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} S(x) = -f(x)$, integration by parts, and then a simple switching of the axis of integration to prove the quantile relationship. I don't know the form of the antiderivative of a general survival or quantile function, but I've tried this for a bunch of distributions and it seems to hold in general, so I would appreciate help in understanding *why* this works and if and how it can be generalized to further moments analytically. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As far as** $\int_0^\infty xS(x) dx = \frac{E(X^2)}{2}.$ For a non negative random variable, we are going to prove that, in general, 
$$\frac{E[X^n]}{n}=\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-1}S(x)\ dF(x).$$ First, notice that $x^n=n\int_0^xt^{n-1}\ dt.$ So,

$$\frac{E[X^n]}{n}=\frac1n\int_0^{\infty}x^{n}\ dF(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^xt^{n-1}\ dt\ dF(x).$$ Changing the order of integration, we get

$$\frac{E[X^n]}{n}=\int_0^{\infty}t^{n-1}\int_t^{\infty}dF(x)\ dt=\int_0^{\infty}t^{n-1}S(t)\ dt.$$

---

**As far as** $\int_0^1 \left[F^{-1}(p)\right]^2 dp$. Substitute $u=F^{-1}(p)$. Then $p=F(u)$ and $dp=dF(u)$.

$$\int_0^{1}[F^{-1}(p)]^n\ dp=\int_0^{\infty}u^n\ dF(u)=E[X^n].$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @zoli, for that clean, crisp, and clear answer!